# Implementation of Sieve of Eratosthenes in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x, sieve-of-eratosthenes

The following is my implementation of Sieve of Eratosthenes. Can somebody please review it? Am I adhering to the algorithm and is it a reasonable implementation of it?

```
def SieveofEratosthenes(primeseries):

    i=1
    primeserieslist = []
    while(i<primeseries):
        i=i+1
        primeserieslist.append(i)

    x=2

    primeslist = []

    while x <= primeseries and x*2 <= primeseries:
        j=2
        while (j < primeseries):
            z = j*x
            if (z <= primeseries):
                if (z in primeserieslist):
                    primeserieslist.remove(z)
            j = j+1

        x=x+1

    print primeserieslist




SieveofEratosthenes(1000000)
```

Comment: Since you asked "Am I adhering to the algorithm and is it a reasonable implementation of it?", I wanted to point you to this beautiful paper which discusses the very question "when is an implementation of an algorithm faithful to the algorithm" in the specific context of the Sieve Of Eratosthenes: [*The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes* by Melissa E. O'Neill](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf), and also the [discussion of this paper on Lambda-the-Ultimate](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3127).

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thank you so much for pointing to the links.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Code review

**Advice 1**

`primeslist` is not used. Remove it from your code.

**Advice 2**

`x=2`: [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) requires to put two spaces around the operator `=`.

**Advice 3**

Also PEP 8 complains about `while (j < primeseries):`. Those parentheses (`()`) are not required; remove them in order to reduce the visual clutter.

**Advice 4**

The identifier `primeserieslist` is misspelled: it should be `prime_series_list`. Actually, the role of that very list is to hold the actual prime sieve, so why not rename it simply to `sieve`?

**Advice 5**

```
if (z <= primeseries):
    if (z in primeserieslist):
        primeserieslist.remove(z)
```

could be written as

```
if z <= prime_series and z in prime_series_list:
    prime_series_list.remove(z)
```

**Advice 6**
`SieveofEratosthenes`: in Python, CamelCase identifiers are suggested to be used for naming classes. What comes to function naming, your name should be `sieve_of_eratosthenes`.

**Advice 7**
`x = x + 1`: you can write more succinctly `x += 1`.

**Advice 8**
Both operations `prime_series_list.remove()` and `z in prime_series_list` run in average linear time, and, thus, are inefficient. See below for more efficient implementation.

## Alternative implementation

Your implementation works and seems correct, yet there is room for improvement code style -wise and efficiency-wise:

```
def sieve_of_eratosthenes(max_integer):
    sieve = [True for _ in range(max_integer + 1)]
    sieve[0:1] = [False, False]
    for start in range(2, max_integer + 1):
        if sieve[start]:
            for i in range(2 * start, max_integer + 1, start):
                sieve[i] = False
    primes = []
    for i in range(2, max_integer + 1):
        if sieve[i]:
            primes.append(i)
    return primes
```

I have set up [this benchmark](https://gist.github.com/coderodde/de839f1ace994550903e29f375a860c1). From it, I get the output:

> ```
> SieveofEratosthenes in 17560 milliseconds.
> sieve_of_eratosthenes in 31 milliseconds.
> Algorithms agree: True
> ```

Any question? Give me a message.

Comment: Thank you so much for your insightful code review along with your comments. Enormously thankful for identifying the areas of improvement. It will surely take time for comprehending your  answer and will make that effort towards understanding it.

Comment: No, PEP8 does not require a space around each binary operator. Actually it contains examples showing the opposite, such as `x = x*2 - 1`.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Thank you for letting me know! I will fix it soon.

Comment: i have an improvement solution, when you created the sieve list use this to increase performance 'sieve = [True] * (max_integer+1)' instead of list comprehension @coderodde

Answer (score 3):

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) asks that you choose a name like `def sieve_of_eratosthenes()`. A name like `limit` would have been more appropriate than `primeseries`, and naming a list `primeserieslist` is just redundant, better to call it e.g. `candidates` or `sieve`.

In the `while` loop you might use `i += 1`, but the whole loop could be replaced with `primeserieslist = list(range(1, primeseries))`.

This expression:

```
if (z in primeserieslist):
```

is very expensive. First please drop the parentheses, `if z in primeserieslist:` suffices. Second, please understand it is doing a linear scan through a long list, giving you yet another nested loop which will slow you down. Rather than a slow O(n) probe of a list, you want a fast O(1) probe of a set. So the initialization above should be `primeserieslist = set(range(1, primeseries))`.

Using two tests here is odd:

```
while x <= primeseries and x*2 <= primeseries:
```

One test would suffice. Again the `while` loops might be more clearly described with `for` running through a `range`. Your test of whether `z` is within range should be combined with the `while` loop's exit criterion.

Comment: Note that `x in set` is O(n) in the worst case.

Comment: Claiming that the OP will encounter linear cost for testing set membership makes no sense. I think you're referring to https://hg.python.org/releasing/3.6/file/tip/Objects/setobject.c#l184 . The constant 9 is, I assert, "small", much smaller than N growing without bound in big-O notation. The worst case linear assessment on https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity may be true in some adversarial settings, but the natural numbers do not pose such a setting. The OP will find that the standard hash function will perform nicely.

Comment: I agree with you that this worst case is a highly unlikely one.